# Django, extending admin's templatetags

Tags: django, admin, templatetags

I want to add an templatetag to the django admin, how can I go around extending the existing tags without needing to fudge in django.contrib.admin.templatetags?

**Update:**

Using {% load mytemplatetags %} in the admin templates breaks my server for some reason (im using nginx and throws me a bad gateway for that page). But the file mytemplatetags.py does exist in the templatetags module of my app.

Interestingly enough when I just misspell or apply a non-existing name for it, forinstance say {% load footemplatetags %} it just gives me an ordinary django error:

```
'footemplatetags' is not a valid tag library
```

So it probably knows mytemplatetags.py's existance, but doens't know how to handle it.

I am using django 1.3 alpha (just checked out the svn), perhaps its a good idea to get with something stable?

Comment: This question isn't very clear. You can define a templatetag in any application and use it from any template, so it's not obvious what you mean by 'adding a templatetag to the admin'. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well the templatetags i have defined in my main application, are not accessible within the admin templates, but I would like to use one of my templatetags there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, my template tag was broken.